# Android, таблица

Tags: android-sdk

Как можно нарисовать рамку, а в нее вставить несколько TextView? Чтобы было понятно, скину фото. А так же, как можно регулировать размер рамки (задавать размер через sp\dp), количество колонок и прозрачность линий рамки?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таблицу можно сделать с помощью TableLayout.

Чтобы у таблицы появилась рамка задайте цвет рамки в качестве фонового (атрибут backgrouund) у TableLayout, а для элементов, которые вложены в TableRow другой фоновый цвет.

Если зададите background у TableLayout чёрным, а у элементов вложенных в TableRow белым, то таблица будет оформлена как у Вас на рисунке.